# How to get the Key when i clicked the item on recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an application with search and recycler view.

Here is my search_adapter:

```
public class search_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<search_adapter.SearchViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    ArrayList<String> fullNameList;
    ArrayList<String> dDateList;
    private OnItemClickListener  mListener;
    Snapshot snapshot;

    public search_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> fullNameList, ArrayList<String> dDateList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.fullNameList = fullNameList;
        this.dDateList = dDateList;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public  void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public static class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView clickCard;
        TextView full_Name;
        TextView death_Date;

        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
             full_Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            death_Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_death);

            clickCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardClick);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(listener !=null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
    @Override
    public search_adapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_adapter,parent,false);
        return new search_adapter.SearchViewHolder(view, mListener);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.full_Name.setText(fullNameList.get(position));
        holder.death_Date.setText(dDateList.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fullNameList.size();
    }
```

In this class, i create the view for the recycler view with onclick listener
I also include an interface so that i can pass the position of the clicked item.

Here is my search_activity class:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements search_adapter.OnItemClickListener{

    private RecyclerView mPerson;
    private EditText mFindField;
    public DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    ArrayList<String> fullNameList;
    ArrayList<String> dDateList;
    private search_adapter searchAdapter;
    int position = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);


        //Database Access//
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        //Recycler View//
        mPerson = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.person_list);
        mPerson.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mPerson.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mPerson.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
        mFindField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);


        fullNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        dDateList = new ArrayList<>();


        mFindField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                        if (!editable.toString().isEmpty()){
                            setAdapter(editable.toString());
                        } else {
                            fullNameList.clear();
                            dDateList.clear();
                            mPerson.removeAllViews();
                        }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {

            mDatabase.child("person").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                fullNameList.clear();
                dDateList.clear();
                mPerson.removeAllViews();
                int counter = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String full_name = snapshot.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
                    String dDate = snapshot.child("dDate").getValue(String.class);

                    if (full_name.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){
                        fullNameList.add(full_name);
                        dDateList.add(dDate);
                        counter++;
                    } else if (dDate.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){
                        fullNameList.add(full_name);
                        dDateList.add(dDate);
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if (counter == 15)
                        break;
                }
                searchAdapter = new search_adapter(SearchActivity.this, fullNameList, dDateList);
                mPerson.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

                searchAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(SearchActivity.this);


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    //new search//

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

    }
```

this is where the passed position will go,
but my problem is, I don't know how to get the key of that passed position, I try using getRef like the others did but it's not working.

My goal is for the user to clicked a data on the recycler view, open a new intent, and view all of the details of that certain clicked data.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of names and a list of dates in your adapter, in the same way you can generate and add a list of keys, and in the viewholder onBind method you can bind the key to a field in your viewholder.  And instead of sending position in your on click listener you can send your key.